# Android - what is the directory of the database?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, download

I want to download a database and then use the SQL Open Helper to open the database, 
instead of creating database when application is install or  preload the database with sql-asset-helper.

My question is: what is the directory of the database? or where should I download the database to?

I do not want to download it to SD card because I do not want user to have access to the data base.
and I know how to use download manager to download images and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Context.getDatabasePath()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) and provide the filename. Then your `SQLiteOpenHelper` should only need the filename and not the entire path. Do not use hardcoded paths.